# Is there anyway to use python's manim library on android and ios?

Tags: python-3.x, manim

I love 3blue1brown's videos and have started learning manim. But I was thinking if it possible to run it on android or ios. I tried to install it in pydroid but it didn't work.

Comment: maybe you could use [Manim web](https://eulertour.com/docs). Note that this is limited and some scenes such as linear transformations are not available. Also I think its not the community version but the 3b1b version.